# Border-radius and box-shadow attributes doesnt affect the code

Tags: css, flexbox, border-radius

Hey everyone i am trying to add box-shadow and border radius to my **.card** element. But nothing happens. How do i solve this. And why is this happening? İ have a theory that it's about the flexbox.

And also is there anyone who can critisize my class naming. İ tried using BEM methodology here for the first time. İt was quite long to style them and name them. Am i doing it right ?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background-color: #8F91A2;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px; }

.card {
  width: 45rem;
  height: 17rem;
  background-color: #1E1E24;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  border-radius: 100%; }
  .card__img, .text-box {
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%; }
    .card__img img, .text-box img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; }

.text-box {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #1E1E24; }
  .text-box__up {
    width: 80%;
    height: 75%;
    padding: 1rem; }
    .text-box__up__header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 45%;
      margin-top: .3rem; }
      .text-box__up__header h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0.3rem;
        margin-left: 3rem;
        font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        text-align: center; }
    .text-box__up__text {
      width: 80%;
      height: 25%;
      margin-left: 3rem;
      margin-top: .7rem;
      padding: .2rem;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      color: #FFD046;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: .6rem; }
  .text-box__down {
    width: 80%;
    height: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: .2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem; }
    .text-box__down__element {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white; }
      .text-box__down__element h2 {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0rem;
        font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive; }
      .text-box__down__element span {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card__img"><img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623654517565-d9886645bb8a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1525&q=80"
                        alt=""></div>
                <div class="text-box">
                    <div class="text-box__up">
                        <div class="text-box__up__header">
                            <h1>Get insights that help grow your business</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-box__up__text">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima a sapiente consequuntur
                                aliquid
                                minus labore magni aspernatur, nam, aperiam.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box__down">
                        <div class="text-box__down__element">
                            <h2>10K+</h2>
                            <span>Companies</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-box__down__element">
                            <h2>10K+</h2>
                            <span>Companies</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-box__down__element">
                            <h2>10K+</h2>
                            <span>Companies</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: The box-shadow seems to be working fine, maybe there's some other issue you found with it? And regarding the border-radius property, that's a very common mistake we all run into at times. Just set the `overflow` of .card to `hidden`. This makes sure the border is as you want it, and that the inner elements don't come out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Edits:

- `body`: deleted `overflow` and `top` properties. added `align-items: center;` and `height: 100vh`;

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

- `card`: `overflow: hidden;` to hide the corners plus `box-shadow` and `border-radius`.

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px lightskyblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

##### The Code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  background-color: #8F91A2;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.card {
  width: 45rem;
  height: 17rem;
  background-color: #1E1E24;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px lightskyblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.card__img, .text-box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%; 
}
  
.card__img img, .text-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

.text-box {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #1E1E24; 
}
  
.text-box__up {
  width: 80%;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 1rem; 
}

.text-box__up__header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  margin-top: .3rem;
}

.text-box__up__header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center; 
}

.text-box__up__text {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding: .2rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFD046;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .6rem; 
 }

.text-box__down {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: .2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem; 
}

.text-box__down__element {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.text-box__down__element h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive; 
}

.text-box__down__element span {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__img"><img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623654517565-d9886645bb8a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1525&q=80"
                alt=""></div>
        <div class="text-box">
            <div class="text-box__up">
                <div class="text-box__up__header">
                    <h1>Get insights that help grow your business</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box__up__text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima a sapiente consequuntur
                        aliquid
                        minus labore magni aspernatur, nam, aperiam.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-box__down">
                <div class="text-box__down__element">
                    <h2>10K+</h2>
                    <span>Companies</span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box__down__element">
                    <h2>10K+</h2>
                    <span>Companies</span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box__down__element">
                    <h2>10K+</h2>
                    <span>Companies</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned your code a little, the `border-radius` is now working thanks to @Robo Mop for the insight on the comment, `overflow:hidden;` was added to the card class . I suggest Bootstrap, it will make your life easier and also try to organize better your HTML and CSS. With comments even better.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #8F91A2;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 250px; 
}
.card {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 45rem;
    height: 17rem;
    background-color: #1E1E24;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    border-radius:100%;
}
.card__img, .text-box {
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%; 
}
.card__img img, .text-box img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
}
.text-box {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: #1E1E24; 
}
.text-box__up {
  width: 80%;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 1rem; 
}
.text-box__up__header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  margin-top: .3rem; 
}
.text-box__up__header h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  text-align: center; 
}
.text-box__up__text {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: .7rem;
  padding: .2rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFD046;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .6rem; 
}
.text-box__down {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: .2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem; 
}
.text-box__down__element {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white; 
}
.text-box__down__element h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive; 
}
.text-box__down__element span {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <!-- Card start -->
        <div class="card">
        
            <div class="card__img">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623654517565-d9886645bb8a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1525&q=80" alt="">
            </div>
            
            <div class="text-box">
                <div class="text-box__up">
                    <div class="text-box__up__header">
                        <h1>Get insights that help grow your business</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box__up__text">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima a sapiente consequuntur
                            aliquid
                            minus labore magni aspernatur, nam, aperiam.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-box__down">
                    <div class="text-box__down__element">
                        <h2>10K+</h2>
                        <span>Companies</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box__down__element">
                        <h2>10K+</h2>
                        <span>Companies</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-box__down__element">
                        <h2>10K+</h2>
                        <span>Companies</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of card -->
        
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```